# не могу понять как передать stream в return

Tags: java, return

```
public static List<Flight> findPlanesLeavingInTheNextTwoHours(Airport airport) {

    Date maxHour = new Date();

//* вот тут должно быть например String a = *// airport.getTerminals().stream() 

            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getFlights().stream())

            .filter(x -> x.getDate().getHours() < maxHour.getHours()+2)

            .forEach(System.out::println);

    return a; //и вот сюда вернуть его (это я так ради примера написал)
}   // но вот проблема тут должен быть не String а что-то другое и я не могу понять что.
```

Answer (score 3):

Описание того, что вы хотите, мягко говоря, непонятное, но , судя по сигнатуре метода и кускам кода , вы хотите сделать примерно так:

```
public static List<Flight> findPlanesLeavingInTheNextTwoHours(Airport airport) {
    final Date maxHour = new Date();
    return airport.getTerminals().stream()
            .flatMap(terminal -> terminal.getFlights().stream())
            .filter(x -> x.getDate().getHours() < maxHour.getHours() + 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: вот только когда так делаю у меня всё красным загорается

Comment: добавляйте классы Airport , Terminal, Flight и будем разбираться

Comment: и да вы правы мне нужно передать конечное значение этого стрима в return

Comment: стрим в ответе написан верно, проблема не в нем. а вот в чем проблема я без этих классов сказать не могу...

Comment: в общем я лучше у учителя спрошу :)

Comment: и на этом спасибо